# How can I remove the "\n" character from csv entries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, seeding

I am seeding my database with tags written on a file called tags.csv .I was able to seed the tags, however, when I check in my console, I see a character \n as the last character of the tag name. For example, let s say that **airplane** is the tag name, when I seed, I get the tag name as **airplane\n** 
What am I doing wrong ?

My **db/tags.csv** is the csv file that contains tag entries and it looks like this:

```
airplane
sleeping
travel
```

Now in my **seeds.rb** file ( that is supposed to be seeding the tags) looks like:

```
puts "loading tags..."

# LOADING TAGS
GOD_USER_ID = -1
csv_text    = File.read('db/tags.csv')
csv         = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)

puts "loading tags..."

csv.each_with_index do |row, index| 
  tag = row
  if ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.exists?(name: tag, user_id: GOD_USER_ID, privacy: 'PUBLIC') == false then
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.create(name: tag, user_id: GOD_USER_ID, privacy: 'PUBLIC') 
    if index % 10 == 0
        puts "tag: #{tag} --- index: #{index}"
    end
  else
    if index % 10 == 0
        puts "tag: #{tag}\t(already exists) --- index: #{index}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: '\n' means **Return Key**. While reading the file line by line, just exclude basically last two characters in the lines or search for `\n` substring and remove from the lines.

Comment: Well first off that doesn't look like a CSV file it looks like a 'return' separated file - and you use any kind of separator you want using the CSV library - if you check it out

Comment: @mertyildiran I have no idea how you would do that with the File.read method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `foreach` it should work properly

```
puts "loading tags..."

# LOADING TAGS
GOD_USER_ID = -1
puts "loading tags..."

CSV.foreach("#{Rails.root}/db/tags.csv", headers: true) do |row|
  if ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.exists?(name: tag, user_id: GOD_USER_ID, privacy: 'PUBLIC')
    puts "tag: #{tag}\t(already exists) --- index: #{index}" if index % 10 == 0
  else
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.create(name: tag, user_id: GOD_USER_ID, privacy: 'PUBLIC')
    puts "tag: #{tag} --- index: #{index}" if index % 10 == 0
  end
end
```

Comment: I solved it already. Had to use a simple  tag = row.gsub('\n', ' ') to remove the \n